# Async Cancellation Exception Metro Dialog

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, mahapps.metro, cancellation-token

I am using a MahApps Metro dialog using the ShowMessageAsync method. There are some occasions where I will call the dialog and then cancel it.  I am calling the dialog as so

```
MetroDialogSettings Settings = new MetroDialogSettings();
Settings.CancellationToken = Token;
Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
await this.ShowMessageAsync("Prompt", "Prompt", MessageDialogStyle.Affirmative, Settings);
```

and cancelling as so

```
private void CancelDialog(CancellationTokenSource cts)
{
    this.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => cts.Cancel()));
}
```

this seems to work well when i tested it using the following example

```
Task.Delay(1000).ContinueWith(_=>CancelDialog(cs));
```

I have also used Token.`ThrowIfCancellationRequested();` because there is an asyncronicity between the show and cancel.  My problem is it works fine if I cancel before the Show and it works fine if I cancel after the Show but it throws a NullReference Exception if i cancel it between 0~500ms after the show.  It appears that something in MahApps code isn't right causing it to except if it is canceled before fully initialized.  I tried to do figure a way out to lock it so I can only cancel once its initialized but I cant find a way to tell if its ready?

**Update:**

This is simplified down to exactly what fails.  The following code throws the NullRefernce Exception

```
CancellationTokenSource cs = new CancellationTokenSource();
MetroDialogSettings settings = new MetroDialogSettings();
settings.CancellationToken = cs.Token;
this.ShowMessageAsync("Prompt", "Prompt", MessageDialogStyle.Affirmative, settings);
this.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => cs.Cancel()));
```

**Update 2:**
This causes an exception:

```
CancellationTokenSource cs = new CancellationTokenSource();
MetroDialogSettings settings = new MetroDialogSettings();
settings.CancellationToken = cs.Token;
var result = this.ShowMessageAsync("Prompt", "Prompt", MessageDialogStyle.Affirmative, settings);
Task.Delay(400).ContinueWith(_ => this.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => cs.Cancel())));
```

While this doesn't:

```
CancellationTokenSource cs = new CancellationTokenSource();
MetroDialogSettings settings = new MetroDialogSettings();
settings.CancellationToken = cs.Token;
var result = this.ShowMessageAsync("Prompt", "Prompt", MessageDialogStyle.Affirmative, settings);
Task.Delay(500).ContinueWith(_ => this.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => cs.Cancel())));
```

Comment: Please show the code around `Task.Delay(1000).ContinueWith(_=>CancelDialog(cs));`, that is likely where the bug is that causes the null reference exception. The important thing we need to see is `cs`, how is it assigned and is `cs = null;` ever done?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I have added a more detailed layout of what does/doesn't cause exceptions

Comment: What is the stack trace of the exception?